# Using SQL statment I would like to work out the average amount per ID 3 months after cutover months

Tags: sql-server

```
    CHARGE_AMT   MONTH    CUTOVER_MONTH        ID
----------   ------   ---------            -------
    300.34   201304   201309               9762373
    456.50   201305   201309               9762373
    567.16   201305   201312               5111852
    451.26   201306   201309               9762373
    557.49   201306   201312               5111852
    466.94   201307   201309               9762373
    566.53   201307   201312               5111852
    458.78   201308   201309               9762373
    500.50   201309   201309               9762373
    566.39   201308   201312               5111852
    573.59   201309   201312               5111852
    590.96   201310   201312               5111852
    641.22   201311   201312               5111852
```

Using SQL statment i would like to work out the average amount per ID 3 month after cutover month. For example I want the average of these amount 458.78, , 451.26, 466.94   for ID 9762373. Without using ID number in the where clause. I want to use the sql in a multiple records.

Comment: what SQL have you tried? and, where did you have a problem with it?

Comment: Why do you need to accomplish such a feat?  what problem will selecting that particular set of records solve, and why don't you want to use the month?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+ (and that you want the 3 latest rows according to `MONTH`):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [MONTH] DESC)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've twigged the data a bit and the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will use the `ROWNUMBER` column (extract records for each id with greatest rownumber)

```
   select Charge_amt, [Month], [RowNumber], [ID]
   from 
     (
        select Charge_amt, [Month], [RowNumber], [ID], ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition BY ID   Order By [RowNumber] desc)  as rownum
        from yourtable
      )data
   where     rownum <= 3
```

EDIT:

The Query below will extract the 3 most recent entries for each ID and it will produce an average value for it:

```
SELECT AVG(Charge_amt) average_amount,  [ID]
FROM 
     (
        SELECT Charge_amt, [Month], CurrentMonth, [ID], ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition BY ID   Order By CurrentMonth desc)  as rownum
        FROM temp
        -- optional WHERE CurrentMonth <= (your cut off month here)
      )data
WHERE     rownum <= 3
GROUP BY ID
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdc5a/3

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've twigged the data a bit and the question.

Comment: Hey Milen, thanks for your input. However i need the only the 3months after cut over date. Example if cutover is 201304, Avg Amount for these months(201303, 201302, 201301). That's the last 3 months after cutover.

Comment: use the  inner `where` clause then to specify Moth or CurrentMonth